# Is there an algorithm to schedule an agent to a maximum number of locations and group them with the maximum number of other agents in a timeslot?

Tags: algorithm, schedule

Given a set of locations, a set of agents and a number of time-slots. Is there a known algorithm that would maximise the number of locations an agent is assigned, while also maximising the number of other agents grouped with?

The number of agents assigned to each location should be balanced as best as possible.

---

Here is an example: Given 3 locations, 6 agents and 3 timeslots. It is possible to assign each agent to every location and assure that they are grouped with every other agent.

**Time-slot 1:**

| Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Agent1 | Agent3 | Agent5 |
| Agent2 | Agent4 | Agent6 |

**Time-slot 2:**

| Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Agent5 | Agent2 | Agent1 |
| Agent3 | Agent6 | Agent4 |

**Time-slot 3:**

| Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Agent4 | Agent1 | Agent2 |
| Agent6 | Agent5 | Agent3 |

In this example each agent is grouped with every other agent once and they are assigned to each location once.

---

Is there a known algorithm to generalise this example to maximise the the number of locations and other agents each agent is assigned when the number of locations, agents and timeslots is varied?

I have tried first prioritising location and then agents not yet grouped when assigning an agent to a timeslot. I have also tried scoring each location in a timeslot based off of already present teams. But wondered if this problem had been dealt with before.

Comment: The question does not give constraints on the number of agents to be assigned to each location. Do you assume exactly two agents per loc and time? If there is no such constraint, you can always achieve the maximum by assigning all agents at the same location for each time. I.e., in time slot 1, everyone is at loc1, in time slot 2, everyone is at loc2, and in time slot 3, everyone is at loc3. Then all agents are assigned to all location and are paired with all others.

Comment: @KotaMori It should be unbounded but balanced. I'll update the question.

Comment: In general you end up trying to find combinatorial designs, which typically require bespoke construction. The broadest construction is that, for every prime power q (q = 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, etc.), there is a perfect solution with q^2-q agents, q locations, and q time slots (in the example in your question, q = 3).